# Laravel 7, How add and change key field login auth

Tags: authentication, field, laravel-7

I want to add and use a field DNI instead of email as key of login.

Something goes wrong, becouse I get this error message after write values on view login:

**Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 

Field 'dni' doesn't have a default value 

(SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (MAU, mau@mau.com, $2y$10$Je2/mfz40q/QApBhkA0fMOiYKy1f/ZHizHW2d8XQS7.5763bclYbq, 2020-07-22 03:31:32, 2020-07-22 03:31:32))**

What I did, 
I changed the users migration in order to add DNI field.

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('dni')->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Then I changed the model, line in app/User.php to:

```
protected $fillable = [
      'dni', 'name', 'email', 'password',
];
```

I has changed app/database/factories/UserFactory.php (I dont sure if it is necesary):

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'dni' => $faker->unique(),
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

I change the login and register views too, adding DNI field before email field ( app/resources/views/auth/register.blade.php):

```
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="dni" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('DNI') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="dni" type="text" class="form-control @error('dni') is-invalid @enderror" name="dni" value="{{ old('dni') }}" required autocomplete="dni">

                                @error('dni')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

[image]

and after that, the error ocurrs.
It seems like the field "dni" is not in the model, the mysql insert not include the dni field.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you actually migrate the migration which is adding a `dni` field to user table? How does the migration look?

Comment: Hi Norgul. Thanks for reading. Now, I included the migration code.

Comment: Okay, and what is happening when you are registering a user? What does your form look like, what data are you forwarding to it?

Comment: Norgui, now I included data that you mencioned.

Comment: Gotcha, I will include the answer in a post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using native Laravel auth components, you will need to override a few things.

There is a `RegisterController` in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth`, and you need to tell Laravel to create a user using your additional properties:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'dni' => $data['dni'],
    ]);
}
```

And you could also override the validation in the same fashion if you need it (not required though):

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'dni' => ['required'],
    ]);
}
```

If you need login to function with DNI as being mandatory, you will also need to change `LoginController` by overriding some of the default methods. This is a bit more complex in a way that I can't really test and verify it for your case, so you'd have to play around. But for starters:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'dni' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->username(), 'password', 'dni');
}
```

If you'd like to see where does it come from, it is from an `AuthenticatesUsers` trait in `vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/`.

Comment: Perfect @Norgui !!!! It's works ok!
So I will ask you another thing about this. I am thinking to mainteince the login only with dni and password,   and I will move the email and email confirm logic, to another table with others fields data from users. Can I reuse all the logic about email and email confirm? will be it very complicated?

Comment: Since `VerificationController` is responsible for it, I presume you could split it. That part you'd have to experiment though :) Please accept the answer if it answers your question